# How to add a class on the clicked element only in this case

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add the class on the clicked element only

But sometimes i see that two items are being selected , could you please let me know how to resolve this

This is my code

```
$(document).on('click', '.resp-tabs-list li', function(event){
    $(".resp-tabs-list li ").removeClass('resp-tab-active');
    $(this).addClass('resp-tab-active');
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1f5n9qo/10/)

Comment: Your code works fine. You say "sometimes". Can you tell us what is the sometimes?

Comment: could not reproduce. Even with fast clicking. Can you elaborate when this is supposed to happen?

Comment: okay ,click on asia and then Europe , you see that both of them are being shown as seelcted

Comment: No, i can't see it.... :(

Comment: is it true , i have cleared the cache as well .

Answer (score 0):

I am making an assumption that "sometimes" happens when you are doing quick clicking between your LI's:

Use `event.stopPropogation()` to ensure proper styling is occurring at the time you need it.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1f5n9qo/11/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.resp-tabs-list li', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".resp-tabs-list li ").removeClass('resp-tab-active');
    $(this).addClass('resp-tab-active');
});
```

Comment: Then you need to define what "sometimes" means.

Comment: okay , in your fiddle , click on asia and then Europe , you see that both of them are being shown as seelcted .

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by "selected"?  The rest-tab-active class is being removed from all li's, then its only being added to the clicked li.  Is there a different state you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion is to delegate the event to the closest static parent if possible. Delegating to the `document` is very expensive because of lookup time for elements from the root.

Everytime event starts from the document root and it gives a lookup to each element to find the specific class name.

If you don't have dynamic elements then you don't need to have `event delegation` at all:

```
$(staticParent).on('click', '.resp-tabs-list li', function(event) {
    $(".resp-tabs-list li ").removeClass('resp-tab-active');
    $(this).addClass('resp-tab-active');
});
```

sometimes in lookup it tends to be slow because of event delegation and usage of class names. As you know **ID selectors are much faster** so you can use that too.

```
$(staticParentID).on('click', '#resp-tabs-list li', function(event) {
    $("#resp-tabs-list li").removeClass('resp-tab-active');
    $(this).addClass('resp-tab-active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
    $('.resp-tabs-list li').on('click',function(){

       $(this).parent().children().removeClass('resp-tab-active');

       $(this).addClass('resp-tab-active');
    });
```